# How to start developing applications for Samsung Corby S3653 WiFi?

Tags: c#, java, mobile

I want to develop applications for this mobile phone but I don't know where to start. For example first thing I need is to develop a call recorder app to record incoming & outgoing calls.

I've downloaded Java ME Platform SDK 3.0 (+ Java SDK) and tested with hello world and it was up and running :). Any suggestions for resources about mobile development are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard Telephony API for JavaME/MIDP.

You can develop other kind of applications on your phone using the JavaME SDK but you won't be able to create the call recorder application you describe.

Comment: So you mean I need to develop my own API or get it somewhere on the web? Or I need to use any other ide designed for Samsung Headset Platform (SHP)

Comment: Mostly, I mean that you can't develop a JavaME call recorder application for the Corby. Not unless you work from inside either Samsung or one of its close technical partners.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you poke around on [this link](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_mdl_name=GT-S3653), you will find a software download that appears to be a plugin or whatever for Visual Studio.</strike>

It turns out that NPS is some kind of software/firmware installer application.

Comment: I only see "SAMSUNG New PC Studio" as software..?

Comment: @HasanGursoy - that is what I am referring to.

Comment: I don't think PC Studio is for coding and also it does not have any connection for VS or any other IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I've found development tools for Samsung at http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just install the SDK, add Samsung reference libraries to your project file if you're developing on Eclipse. Tested on emulators, and it works swell... =)